# SpriteKit and Multithreading

Tags: multithreading, sprite-kit

I am developing a little/mid RTS game with SpriteKit.
I wonder if my multithreaded approach is OK.

Generally speaking I have user controlled units and enemy units. 
Both units has a basic AI, enemies obviously has some more AI

Lets say if unit is standing still and enemy unit is approached to its attacking range I want a unit to Automagically attack the enemy. 
And ofcourse same for the enemy.

I choosed not to add a logic and distance measurements to the update method which is expensive.

I decided to make 2 threads/queues/pools whatever with own update method. 1 thread for enemies and 2 for units respectively.

Question: Is it ok/fine/bad/acceptable approach ? 
Do I get benefits from it or contrary?

Comment: The problem with threads is you can't guarantee when they fire.  You could go through 3 update cycles before it happens, and in those 3 cycles your entire game state may change.  Now for your distance problem, you should only have to calculate the distance once,  then keep track of the delta change when you or the target moves

Comment: @knight0fdragon I have tested the case with 500ms delay on the secondary thread which means I am loosing atleast 30 update cycles. The result impressed me - the game looks fine UI wise and unit responsiveness is quitebacceptable with such a big delay. So ir seems to vary a lot on many things that are going on. Also next week or so I want to smooth it all up with predictions and stuff. About a physics I have tried it already today and have diacovered interesting things: amount of bodies doesn't affect the FPS that much, but having them does:-( -> I mean FPS reduced by ~same with 20 and 3k units

Comment: @knight0fdragon I guess I will have to roll my own collision/hit testing routines - lined up with predictions(if implemented decently) should do the game with not much lags (I think). or do you have some other suggestions maybe ? Hits and collisions must be on the main Update thread. About the distances I dont think that measuring the whole distance vs measuring the delta distance has a performance adventages - maybe I dont see a sufficient way of implementing that - but I really cant see how should it speed up the processing

Comment: Addition is faster than multiplecation

Comment: @knight0fdragon But delta calculation itself ?

Comment: That should already be happening

Comment: What do you use to move the troops

Comment: @knight0fdragon For now 'SKAction' move to point , but it may change when I will implement path findings with time that is distance divided by speed

Comment: Ok well in the case of moveto, you need to multiply your distance * (total seconds - elapsed)/total seconds. Other methods like path finding should be telling you the distance travelled along the path

Comment: @knight0fdragon but they can move in different directions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Just my point of view

You say

> I choosed not to add a logic and distance measurements to the update method which is expensive.

So I assume you are write expensive computations involving distance measurements inside a closure you want to execution on a separate thread.

### An example

**Time t0**

A *unit* is near the *enemy*. You start an asynch thread with complex code to determine whether the *unit* should attack the *enemy*.

**Time t1**

Then (on the main thread) the user moves the *unit* far away from the *enemy*.

**Time t2**

Finally the thread started at `t0` completes. The decision is to attack the enemy because at time `t0` the unit was close to the enemy. But now the unit is no longer near the `enemy` so you see a wrong behaviour on the screen.

### Wrap up

If this is an acceptable behaviour for your game then I don't see further problems.

### Another simple solution

If your logic about whether a unit/enemy should attack an enemy/unity is exclusively based on the distance between the 2 objects you could use the physics engine provided by SpriteKit to check for collisions.

**Perimeter**

You can simply create a circular physics body without mass centered on each unit/enemy. Let's call this `Perimeter`.

You also set the bit mask values so that you only receives notification when a unit perimeter and an enemy perimeter collided. So no notification when 2 unit or 2 enemy perimeters collides.

Now the physics engine will notifier you each time a unit is close enough an enemy. no need for multithreading and very easy code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out sir, however I am not starting the thread, it is constantly running with fixed delta time. As for your question in the title -> I guess I want because I want to have a lot of units, previously trying to calculate evrything in update method halved my fps with only 100 units. Should I still stick with multithreaded approach ?

Comment: I am very appriciate your answer. I have tried physics approach (in my last question) it reduced FPS significantly even with 20 units on the map.

Comment: Collision detection with 20 units and 20 enemies (with the bitmask property properly set) should be fast enough.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong but I had 37 fps spikes on MBP late 2013 with Nvidia dedicated :-(. what about 1000 units(300 -700) ? Physics simulated for each frame... Manual colision test shares a lot of room for optimizations in my game.  +1 (if i could) for the picture :-)

Comment: fps on simulator is not real

Comment: @appzYourLife but with this logic if an enemy throws a bomb, an archer can die at far distance?

Comment: @SimonePistecchia: Not necessarily, it depends on the logic implemented for the bomb. You can define a radius from the bomb in order to select the affected enemies. The logic I described is only to decide whether a unit/enemy should switch to "attack mode".

Comment: I am not talking about simulators... I developing a MacOS game.

Comment: I've done testing yesterday, the issue described is not noticable, because unit decides to attack in a bg thread which means when it does a distance calculations positions are not chamged significantly, also if it triggered a shot, and it enemy user is moved he simply won't hit it... however I value the answer very much and it really opened my eyes for such states thus I accepted it. P.S. still going with multithreads for now it works fine (UI wise) maybe at some point I will do some mixed approach. Thanks again sir.

Comment: @user3351949: This was an interesting question. If you want you can also add your own answer describing the solution you used.

Comment: Recently I thought to take it further (still need to imolement and test): in my game enemies(AI) are not the bravest creatures they are always going in squads/formations. I think it maybe more realistic if every formation(if there are many formations then group of formations) will have theire private update thread with fixed time. in this case the units won't react to events synchronously. but each will have private reaction time etc... As for the Projectiles and attacks I planning to make them on a main update thread with physics. This maybe interesting :-)

Comment: @user3351949: How are you running the background thread? If you are using Grand Central Dispatch keep in mind that it is not stopped when the game is paused. I don't know if this can be a problem for you.

Comment: For now (in test environment) yes I am using GCD it can be stopped ofcourse -> you can use 'NSCondition' for example to quit or pause the while loop (With 'NSAtomic' instead of BOOL it is very efficient as well. But I think I will get to the 'NSThread's there I can play with priorities more smoothly.

Comment: I making this as a hobby (or more likely implementing a teenage dream) and not on a day job. Well if I will be able to make it happen (or some close POC) I will publish it on some blog and provide source for the "engine addon" not sure how to call it. It is sad there is not much articles like this with SpriteKit even non SpriteKit articles are mere outdated :-(

Comment: I would not recommend using the Physics Engine to be handling this kind of problem, if you have a lot going on (like you do in RTS) you may see some slow down